# Where do I find the questions I've favorited on this forum?

Tags: discussion

I always favorite questions on English Learners to see other people's answers after the fact, but I can't find a tab or anything that I could click on and show me all the questions I've marked as favorite on the app or the website.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your profile page. Click on the tab for "activity." You should see a line of options beginning with the word "summary." "Favorites" should appear in that same line. Click on it, and you should see your favorite questions.